# Cannot find type System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TestProject.Employee>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc. I have been following up tutorials and I was working on this simple hello world project where I am trying to connect my model-controller-view together. Now, I created a strongly typed view for my model class and used aspx as the view engine. But then I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot find type System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage

**This is my view page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TestProject.Employee>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>

web config -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="TestProject" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the System.Web.Mvc dll and make 'copy local' flag to true. Dont forget to update entire solution web.config and view folder config files.

Answer (score 0):

Please check wheather your project has System.Web.Mvc reference added or not.